# Computing $\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1}$ using Fourier series.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

> $f$ is a $2 \pi$ periodic function on $ ] - \pi,\pi[$ defined as :
>
> $$f(x) = e^{-x}$$
>
> Using Fourier series, compute the sums :
>
> $$ \sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} , \sum_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} $$

---

How do I compute $\sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1}$ ?

I have computed the fourier coefficient and found that:

$$a_0 = \frac{2}{\pi} (1 - e^{- \pi}) $$

$$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi(n^2 + 1)} (1 - (-1)^n . e^{- \pi} ) $$

$$b_n = \frac{2n}{\pi(n^2 + 1)} (1 - (-1)^n . e^{- \pi} ) $$

Using Dirichlet theorem and taking $x = 0$ to make the $b_n$ disappear, I get:

$$S_f (1) = \frac{2}{\pi} (1 - e^{- \pi}) + \sum_{n = 1}^{+ \infty} \frac{2}{\pi(n^2 + 1)} (1 - (-1)^n . e^{- \pi} ) . (-1)^n = 1 $$

I do not see how to proceed to get the value of the sum?

The same problem for the second sum.

Comment: "same problem for the second sum" - not exactly; once you find the first sum, multiply it by $2$ and add $1$.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you. I'm still stuck with the first sun though.

Comment: Your coefficients are not correct:
$$a_0=\frac1\pi\int_{-\pi}^\pi e^{-x}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{e^\pi-e^{-\pi}}\pi=\frac{2\sinh\pi}\pi$$
Similarly you should have ended up with
$$a_n=\frac{2(-1)^n\sinh\pi}{\pi(n^2+1)}\text{ and }b_n=\frac{2n(-1)^n\sinh\pi}{\pi(n^2+1)}$$
I think you are just missing a factor of $e^\pi$ in certain places. (NB: $2\sinh\pi=e^\pi-e^{-\pi}$.)

Comment: @user170231 To compute the coefficients, I used the formula: 

$$ a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) cos (nx)$$

and : 


$$ b_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) sin (nx)$$

Isn't it correct?

Comment: Your function is $2\pi$-periodic over the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. The formulae you've used would give the same coefficients if $f(x)\cos nx$ and $f(x)\sin nx$ were even functions/symmetric about $x=0$, but this is not the case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_series#Period_2%CF%80

Comment: @user170231 If the functions are even/ symmetric about $x = 0$. can I still use the formula you used in all cases? I want to keep one method to compute the coefficient with.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: No, that's a very specific condition to meet; you would need to have both $f(-x)\cos(-nx)=f(x)\cos nx$ and $f(-x)\sin(-nx)=f(x)\sin nx$ for all $n$. But then this means you'd need $f(-x)=f(x)=-f(x)$, which only happens for $f(x)=0$...

Comment: It got confusing. I meant the forumula you have used: 

$$a_n = \frac{1}{\pi} \int_{- \pi}^{\pi} f(x) cos(nx)$$

Can I use this formula for all functions without using this one ??: 

$$a_n = \frac{2}{\pi} \int_{0}^{\pi} f(x) cos(nx)$$

since I can only use this one only if the function is even or symmetric.

Comment: The formula I cited specifically works *only* for functions that are $2\pi$-periodic over the interval $(-\pi,\pi)$. There is a formula for $P$-periodic functions over the interval $(x_0,x_0+P)$ listed on the page I linked under the section "A more general definition" (Eq. 4) for the more general case. It suggests$$a_n=\frac2\pi\int_0^\pi f(x)\cos nx\,\mathrm dx$$works for a function $f(x)$ that is $\pi$-periodic over $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: @user170231 Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the correct coefficients (see comments), you have for $x \in]-\pi,\pi[$:

$$
e^{-x} = \frac{2}{\pi} \sinh(\pi) + 2 \sinh(\pi) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n  (n\sin (nx) + \cos(nx)) }{\pi(n^2 + 1)} 
$$

so

$$
e^{x} + e^{-x} = \frac{4}{\pi} \sinh(\pi)  + 4 \sinh(\pi) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ (-1)^n \cos(nx) }{\pi(n^2 + 1)} 
$$

Now we can evaluate this for $x \to \pm\pi$. To be more precise (see the answer by @kvantour), the evaluation $x \to \pm\pi$ corresponds to the average of the two values at $\pm\pi$ which is exactly what the Fourier series converges to at this point of discontinuity.

$$
\cosh (\pm \pi) = \frac{2}{\pi} \sinh(\pi)+ 2 \sinh(\pi) \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 }{\pi(n^2 + 1)} 
$$

and in turn

$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1 }{(n^2 + 1)}  = \frac{\pi \coth(\pi) -1}{2  }
$$

Then the second question follows:
$$
\sum_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} = 1 + 2 \sum_{1}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{n^2 + 1} = \pi \coth(\pi) \simeq 1.0037 \; \pi
$$

Comment: for comparison,
$$
\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} \frac{1}{x^2 + 1} {\rm{dx}} = \pi
$$

Comment: You cannot make the statement $x\rightarrow\pi$ and just know its value. $f(x)$ is discontinuous in that point.

Comment: @kvantour Thank you. I have adressed that point and edited my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When you state *Using Fourier series*, it does not necessarily mean that you have to use the Fourier Cosine and Sine series. You can also write it in exponential form:

> Any periodic function $\tilde{f}(t)$ with period $2\pi$ can be written
>   as:
>
> $$ f(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n\,e^{int} $$ with $$
>  c_n=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi \tilde f(t)\,e^{-int}\,\textrm{d}t
>  $$
>   **note:** we make a distinction between the fourier series $f(t)$ and the periodic function $\tilde f(t)$ to indicate that they are different when $\tilde f(t)$ is discontiniuous.

When you apply this for $\tilde f(t)$,  which is periodic over $2\pi$, discontinuous and defined in the region $]-\pi,\pi[$ as $\exp(-t)$, you obtain

$$
c_n = \frac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi\cdot\frac{(-1)^n\,(1-in)}{1+n^2}
$$

giving you:

$$
f(t)=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n\,(1-in)}{1+n^2}\,e^{int}
$$

You already notice the familiar part in the sum which is of interest, the problem is the $(-1)^n$. This we can get rid of with the proper choice of $t$. If $t=\pm\pi$ then $\exp(\pm in\pi)=(-1)^n$. But be advised *$f(t)$ is periodic with a period of $2\pi$ and is not continuous in the points $t=n\pi$*. The value the Fourier Series will return is:

$$ f(\pi)=f(-\pi)= \frac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(1-in)}{1+n^2} = \frac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}$$

The latter reduction of the sum is straightforward as the imaginary part is zero.

But we cannot use this, as we do not know what $f(\pi)$ is since $\tilde f(t)$ is discontinuous at these points. Luckily, some smart people solved this conundrum and showed that at a discontinuity, the Fourier series converges to the average of the two values, i.e.

$$ f(\pi)=f(-\pi)=\frac{\lim_{t\rightarrow\pi^-}\tilde f(t) + \lim_{t\rightarrow \pi^+}\tilde f(t)}{2} = \frac{\exp(-\pi)+\exp(\pi)}{2} = \cosh(\pi)$$

See: [Fourier series at discontinuities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/48798/fourier-series-at-discontinuities)

So in the end, we have the solution:
$$f(\pi)=\cosh(\pi)=\frac{\sinh(\pi)}\pi \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}$$
or

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{\pi \coth(\pi)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}=1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{1+n^2}}$$

**remark:** computing $f(0)$ gives directly, without any fuss:

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #000000]{\frac{\pi}{\sinh(\pi)}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{1+n^2}}$$

Comment: I computed the sum using $f(0)$, but I will pay more attention to the points of discontinuity, so thank you so much for your additional important information.

Answer (score -2):

Try using Parseval's theorem,

$$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f(x)|^2 dx = \frac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n^2+b_n^2$$

If it comes out too nasty, then I think your coeffecients might be off.

Comment: I do not see how Parseval's theorem will give me the sum, can you elaborate more? Although, I have checked the coefficient well. They seem to be correct.